# Does gl_Position set the center of the rectangle when using GL_POINTS?

Tags: ios, windows, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a C#/OpenGL code base that runs on several platforms: iOS/OpenGL ES 2.0 through MonoTouch, Windows/OpenGL through OpenTK, as well as others.

When switching from quads to `GL_POINTS` rendering, I noticed that the rectangles I'm drawing are rendered with an offset on iOS.

It seems that, on Windows, **`gl_Position` defines the center** of the rectangle to be drawn. This is the behavior I'm expecting.

On iOS/OpenGL ES 2.0/MonoTouch, **`gl_Position` seems to set the upper-left corner** of the rectangle.

I have spent several hours trying to identify the cause for this, because, of course, I think that this is caused by a bug in my code.

But before I lose more time on that: **When using `GL_POINTS`, what exactly does `gl_Position` define?** The center or the corner of the rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_POINTS` are not rectangles, first and foremost. It is an easy assumption to make, but implementations may draw them as circles if you enable point smoothing (deprecated) or multisampling. Point primitives are clipped against the location defined by `gl_Position`, but rasterization behaves as described [here](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/glspec1.1/node44.html#SECTION00630000000000000000).

My best guess has to do with sub-pixel precision during rasterization, GL ES tends to have less of it and things that have to be snapped to integer coordinates will behave less favorably. You can try a sub-pixel shift (e.g. 0.375 or 0.5) and see if that changes anything. Compliant implementations of OpenGL and OpenGL ES are both subject to the same rules when it comes to rasterizing point primitives.

Out of curiosity, what point size are you using? Anything other than exactly **1.0** is not guaranteed to be supported. Coupled with things like point size granularity, limited range and variable rasterization shape, `GL_POINTS` are actually a poor substitute for quads.

Comment: I'm using quite large values for `gl_PointSize`, some of them are more than 100 pixels. I'm gonna investigate further, and most likely I will return to using quads.

Comment: That will not work on a **lot** of implementations. You can query the point size range this way: `GLfloat point_min_max [2]; glGetFloatv (GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, point_min_max);`. The minimum size will be `point_min_max [0]` and the maximum will be `point_min_max [1]`. Most implementations will support **1.0** for the minimum and somewhere around **63.5** for the maximum, but OpenGL only requires implementations to support exactly **1.0**.